# What is difference between AL programming language and X++ language in Dynamic 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-al

I am trying to learn Dynamic 365 and I need to know what is difference between AL Programming langauge and X++. what are the usage of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AL is the language used to customize Dynamics 365 Business Central (info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/intro-basics-al-programming/)

X++ is the language used to customize Dynamics 356 F&O (info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/get-started-xpp-finance-operations/)

They are two separate products inside Dynamics 365 family.

Comment: Thanks for your Ans. So I can't use AL to customize Dynamics 365 CRM ?. I can only use X++ to customize dynamic 365 CRM ?

Comment: for Dynamics CRM/Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement you use C#, you don't use AL or X++